# Alias that will create directory if original is non-existent

Tags: macos, alias, osx-mountain-lion, quartz-composer

I am making a piece of software built in Quartz Composer that I would like to distribute for testing while keeping installation - even from the ground up without Quartz Composer installed - very easy and simple.

I want people to be able to drag the correct plugins and files into the correct directories (Similar to the [Tryplex Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/tryplex/)) easily: so I am opting for an alias approach within Mac OSX. This works fine if the directory the alias points to is in the correct place or is at least in existence.

However, if the folder or directory is non-existent (such as the 'Quartz Composer Plugin' folder) then the alias will be broken. The user may then delete or fix the alias by hand to remedy. But, instead of this, I would like the alias to create a directory in a specified position if the directory is not found.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Aliases can't do that.

Your best option is probably to make an installer `.pkg` using PackageMaker (it's available in the Mac Dev Center as part of the "Auxiliary Tools" download).